# Grails resources with content delivery networks: How to avoid mixed content?

Tags: grails, cdn

When using the grails resources plugin to serve resources through a content delivery network like Amazon CloudFront, how do you handle the case where pages are accessed with both HTTP and HTTPS?

If the CDN base URL is HTTP, a HTTPS page will result in a mixed content warning.

As far as I see, the resources plugin only allows a single mapping and I don't see a way to post-process the generated URIs in the resources taglib.

Comment: what about just doing your resources as https?

Comment: That would increase HTTP page load times, so I did not consider it. I have found a hack to do what I want, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated version based on the resources 1.2.1 plugin.  The metaMethod is different in this version.  Also the previous code replaced all resources with the CDN version.  If you had resources that were pulling from somewhere else (google jquery cdn for example) the previous code would replace the google cdn with the one from the config.

The previous version also only went from http to https, and not vice versa.  If the delegate.request.scheme was http this new version uses a 2nd configuration parameter for a http cdn entry.  This is useful if you are using something like amazon cloudfront where you pay more for https requests.

```
def originalResolveResourceAndURI = ResourceTagLib.metaClass.getMetaMethod('resolveLinkUriToUriAndResource', [Object])
ResourceTagLib.metaClass.resolveLinkUriToUriAndResource = {args ->
    def result = originalResolveResourceAndURI.invoke(delegate, args)
    String resourceUri = result.uri

    if (resourceUri.startsWith(grailsApplication.config.grails.resources.cdn.http) && delegate.request?.scheme == 'https') {
        result.uri = (resourceUri =~ /http:\/\/[^\/]*/).replaceFirst(grailsApplication.config.grails.resources.cdn.https)
    }
    else if (resourceUri.startsWith(grailsApplication.config.grails.resources.cdn.https) && delegate.request?.scheme == 'http') {
        result.uri = (resourceUri =~ /https:\/\/[^\/]*/).replaceFirst(grailsApplication.config.grails.resources.cdn.http)
    }
    result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up monkey-patching the method in the `ResourceTagLib` class that is responsible for looking up the resources. Add this to `BootStrap.init`:

```
def originalResolveResourceAndURI = ResourceTagLib.metaClass.getMetaMethod('resolveResourceAndURI', [Object])
ResourceTagLib.metaClass.resolveResourceAndURI = {args ->
    def result = originalResolveResourceAndURI.invoke(delegate, args)
    String resourceUri = result.uri
    if (resourceUri.startsWith('http:') && delegate.request?.scheme == 'https') {
        result.uri = (resourceUri =~ /http:\/\/[^\/]*/).replaceFirst(grailsApplication.config.grails.resources.cdn.https)
    }
    result
}
```

and in the config add the property

```
grails.resources.cdn.https=[https URL of CDN]
```